# Autoware.AI vs Autoware.Auto: Path Planners Switch and runtime-manager Interface

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I do not know how to switch path planners in Autoware.Auto such as it is possible on ROS1 Navigation Stack.

Someone know where is it available to dowload path planners for Autoware and how to import and use it in Autoware.Auto
It seems that in Autoware.AI is easier using the Autoware.AI. Does someone here used Autoware.AI for this purpose and could suggest me Autoware.AI path planners tutorial to follow.

My complete doubt is described in the link below:

https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/autowareclass2020/-/issues/89

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374961/autoware.ai-vs-autoware.auto:-path-planners-switch-and-runtime-manager-interface/) by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2021-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In link below this question is answered:

Autoware.Auto still does not have implemented the Runtime Manager Interface for Autoware.Auto (It is just available for Autoware.AI).
It still also does not provide the possibility to switch to different path planners and to create an automatic Benchmark from them as MoveIT framework provides.

---

Originally posted by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) with karma: 266 on 2021-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0